# KeyError in JSON Data Pull with Python

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I'm building a crawler to extract data and I'm having trouble categorizing it all when I get it. It seems that the dict key I was expecting to use will not pull what I am looking for. I want to extract "member_id" and "vote_position".

The example below shows an attempt to pull using the "positions" key. Using "positions", "member_id", "vote_position" all yield the same KeyError.

Moving farther down you can see the output when using `print data`. Still, using the keys displayed after `print data` output still yields KeyError.

I'm feeling pretty stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2
import json
api_key = '72c9a68****************************'
url = 'http://api.time.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/blue/113/
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)

print data['positions']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/untitled2/1", line 8, in <module>
  print data [positions]
NameError: name 'positions' is not defined
```

JSON Data:

```
 "positions": [
          {
            "member_id": "A000055",
            "vote_position": "Yes",
            "dw_nominate": "0.466"
          },
                        {
            "member_id": "A000367",
            "vote_position": "Yes",
            "dw_nominate": "0.995"
          },
```

a simple `print data` yields:

```
{u'dw_nominate': u'-0.311', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001242'},     {u'dw_nominate': u'0.793', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001250'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.728', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001273'}
```

Comment: what gives you `print data.keys()`

Comment: So `data` is a list of dicts -- as the first delimiter in its JSON data is a `[`, **not** a `{` as it would be for a JS "object" (corresponding to a Python dict).  BTW, you _are_ displaying that JSON in a truncated version (there is never a closing `]`) but it definitely seems to lack any leading `{` before the leading `[`; also no closing `'` for `url`...

Comment: It is truncated. It's a long list. The URL doesn't include my API key either, it was just to show the whole program. The code yields results, but I'm having problems deconstructing the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

from what you gave:

```
data = {u'dw_nominate': u'-0.311', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001242'},     {u'dw_nominate': u'0.793', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001250'}, {u'dw_nominate': u'0.728', u'vote_position': u'Yes', u'member_id': u'B001273'}

print type(data) # returns tuple

data[0]['vote_position'] # returns 'Yes'
```

to get all keys:

```
for i in xrange(len(data)): # python 2.x, for python 3, use range()
    print data[i].keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

If this was a simple case of the "`positions`" item not being present, or being spelled incorrectly somewhere, you would get an error like:

```
KeyError: 'positions'
```

Instead, the `NameError` you are seeing is telling you that the variable named `positions` hasn't beed defined. Python is trying to reference a variable with that name, rather than using the string, because of the line that says :

```
print data [positions]
```

which is missing quotes around the word.

(At least according to your traceback:)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/untitled2/1", line 8, in <module>
  print data [positions]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been running it through using every thing I can think of. When I run `print data['positions'] it returns KeyError.